# How to execute gradle tasks in a loop

Tags: gradle, groovy

I want to execute a task multiple times in a loop.
For example.

```
task firsttask{

println"this is first task"
def parsedfile = (new XmlParser()).parse("d:/myfile.xml")
  parsedfile.list.each{
         list-> 
             println"execute second task multiple times"
             tasks.secondtask.execute()

     }
 }


task secondtask<<{
println"this is from second task"

}
```

// this is printing the line "execute second task multiple times" multiple times but task is executing only once. Please help

Comment: Why? What are you really trying to do? IGradle tasks are not functions, it is sort of discouraged generally to explicitly call one task from another. You could always define a function and call that multiple times.

Comment: Instead of defining the functionality as a task, simply create a method and call the method with the file as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am going with custom task, where I can write methods separately and call it n number of times. 
 
Why? What are you really trying to do?-- I have to parse a parent file in one task, from where I can capture child files. Then I have to parse child files one after other. My requirement is if I don't want to parse parent files, I want to parse child files directly.So, this should be written as separate task.. Here what I am trying to do is, in the first task I will parse parent file and get details of child file add to database. For each file I will call child task